# How to model bidirectional relation with a django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three simple models: Country, State, City

A country has several states.
A state has several cities, and only one country.
A city has one state.

I'd like to model this using Django:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ... States ???

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ... Cities ???

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    State = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am not very clear about how to represent the links between State and Country, as well as the links between State and City, since there is no "OneToMany" class.

Additionally, I'd like it to be bidirectional (I'd like to be able to access the state from the cities, as well as the cities from the states and so on..)

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is already the case. Indeed, if you make a [**`ForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), or any other relation, Django will automatically add a conceptual one in reverse.

For a `ForeignKey`, the reverse is by default named `modelname_set` with `modelname` the name of the *source* model in lowercase, so here `state_set` and `city_set`. You can specify a different one by specifying the [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

But this thus means that if you have a `Country` model object, you can work with:

```
united_states.state_set.all()
```

to get all `State` records with `united_states` as `country`. This will then thus make a query that will retrieve the related `State`s.